# Sending mulitple dependent transactions, revert if last one fails

Tags: web3.py, python

I'm able to build and broadcast a simple transaction from a contract:

```
raw_tx = contract.functions.someFunction()

tx_params = {
    "from": WALLET,
    "nonce": nonce,
    "gas": 8000000,
    "gasPrice": w3.toWei("25", "gwei"),
}

tx = raw_tx.buildTransaction(tx_params)

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)

tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

Nothing really hard here. What I would like to do next is bundle two instructions like the one above in one single transaction. If the two instructions are called A and B, I would like A to run first, then B. But if for some reason B fails, I would like A to be reverted. Of course if A fails, we shouldn't proceed to B.

I have been looking around for a few hours but I wasn't able to find anything that would allow me to do that with web3.py.

I have found this SO thread tagged with web3js that claims it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451583/best-practice-of-sending-multiple-dependent-transaction-solana-web3js/71457527#71457527

Apparently it would be possible to:

> you can pack instructions into a single transaction and have any failure fail the transaction as a whole.

So my question would be: can I do that with web3.py? Is it possible at all to do something along those lines (maybe by deploying a contract?)

Comment: SO question is for Solana a different blockchain so it doesn't apply to Ethereum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes. The smart contracts are the one who provides `atomic` transactions.

You need to embed the whole logic into a single contract and trigger a single transaction from `web3.py`.

This is the same reason attackers use smart contracts for attack.

Here is brief sketch

Imagine you have two function in smart contract: `function_A` and `function_B`. What you can do is call `function_B` from `function_A`. On your python script, call `function_A`. If your logic is correct, you embedded two action into a single transaction. If either one of the fails, your transactions reverts!

Comment: Ok, fair. What about the piece of JS from the SO post?

Comment: What about them?